# Buttons on any page inherited from Master firing. Not sure whats stopping it

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, button, onclick

Here is My Master Page Code. None of the buttons on any page inherited from this master is firing. I have no idea what could be stopping it. It's been killing my brains for 3 days. Help, Please? Tried creating new onClick methods etc. Buttons just wont fire. Something somewhere is stopping the button Fire and I;m not sure what it is

```
        <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="master.Master.cs" Inherits="ABSA.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>ABSA Property | Home</title>
<!-- for-mobile-apps -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Plottage Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Android Compatible web template, 
Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />

<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false);
        function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } 
</script>

<!-- //for-mobile-apps -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />


<!-- js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- //js -->

<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<!-- start-smoth-scrolling -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- start-smoth-scrolling -->

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>




    <script src="js2/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css2/style.css" />



<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Different Multiple Form Widget template Responsive, Login form web template,Flat Pricing tables,Flat Drop downs  Sign up Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Login sign up Responsive web template, SmartPhone Compatible web template, free web designs for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="css3/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- //Custom Theme files -->
<!-- font-awesome icons -->
<link href="css3/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<!-- //font-awesome icons -->
<!-- web font -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- //web font -->


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <!-- header -->
    <div class="header">    
        <div class="header-top">

            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="header-top-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span>+270000000</li>
                        <li><a href="mailto:info@example.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>property@absa.co.za</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="header-top-left1">
                    <ul class="social-icons">
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-border facebook"></a></li>

                        <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-border instagram"></a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="header-top-right">
                    <div class="search">
                        <input class="search_box" type="checkbox" id="search_box"/>
                        <label class="icon-search" for="search_box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></label>
                        <div class="search_form">
                            <form action="#" method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search..."/>
                                <input type="submit" value=" "/>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                        <div class="logo">
                            <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.aspx">ABSA<span>Real Estate</span></a></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wil" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="HelpUSell.aspx" class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Absa Help Us Sell</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Something.aspx" class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom">Absa Properties</a></li>
                                <li><a href="FAQ.aspx" class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom">FAQ's</a></li>
                                <li><a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="hvr-bounce-to-bottom modal_close2">Login</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>


                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                </nav>
            </div>




    <section id="SigninModal" class="popupBody" >


                <div class="top-grids-left">
                    <div class="signin-form-grid">
                        <div  id="modal" class="signin-form main-agile popupContainer" style="display:none;">
                            <p style="text-align:right;"><span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times "></i></span></p>
                            <h2>SIGN IN</h2>
                            <form id="signin" action="#" method="post">
                                <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required="" runat="server"/>
                                <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required="" runat="server"/>   
                                <input type="checkbox" id="brand" value="" runat="server"/>
                                <label for="brand" runat="server"><span></span> Remember me ?</label> 
                                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" type="submit" runat="server" Text="SIGN IN"/>


                                <div class="signin-agileits-bottom"> 
                                    <p><a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a></p>    
                                    <p><a class="modal_close" id="modal_trigger2" href="#modal2" runat="server">Register </a></p> 

                                </div> 
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <!-- //main --> 

    </section>




    <section class="popupBody">


                <div class="top-grids-left">
                    <div class="signin-form-grid">
                        <div  id="modal2" class="signin-form main-agile popupContainer" style="display:none;">
                            <p style="text-align:right;"><span class="modal_close2"><i class="fa fa-times "></i></span></p>
                            <h3>REGISTER</h3>
                        <form id="register">
                            <input type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" required="" runat="server"/>
                            <input type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name" required="" runat="server"/>
                             <input type="text" name="Contact" placeholder="Contact Number" required="" runat="server"/>
                            <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Your Email" required="" runat="server"/>
                            <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required="" />
                            <input type="checkbox" id="brand1" value="" runat="server"/>
                            <label for="brand1"><span></span>I accept the terms of use</label>
                             <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Text="REGISTER" OnClick="btnRegister_Click"/>
                        </form>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>

    <!-- //main --> 

    </section>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({ top: 200, overlay: 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });
            $("#modal_trigger2").leanModal({ top: 200, overlay: 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close2" });

    $(function(){
        // Calling Login Form
        $("#login_form").click(function(){
            $(".social_login").hide();
            $(".user_login").show();
            return false;
        });

        // Calling Register Form
        $("#modal_trigger2").click(function () {

            $(".social_login").hide();
            $(".user_register").show();
            $(".header_title").text('Register');
            return false;
        });

        // Going back to Social Forms
        $(".back_btn").click(function(){
            $(".user_login").hide();
            $(".user_register").hide();
            $(".social_login").show();
            $(".header_title").text('Login');
            return false;
        });

    })
</script>

<!-- //header -->


        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   </div>
        </div>

        <!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="footer-grids">
                <div class="col-md-2 footer-grid" style="font-size:12px">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="mail.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Security Estates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Site Map</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Property for Sale By Suburb</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 footer-grid">
                    <div class="footer-grid1">
                        <div class="footer-grid1-left">
                            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive"/></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer-grid1-right">
                            <a href="single.html">Property 1</a>
                            <div class="m1">
                                <a href="single.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-grid1">
                        <div class="footer-grid1-left">
                            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive"/></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer-grid1-right">
                            <a href="single.html">Property 2</a>
                            <div class="m1">
                                <a href="single.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-grid1">
                        <div class="footer-grid1-left">
                            <a href="single.html"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive"/></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer-grid1-right">
                            <a href="single.html">Property 3</a>
                            <div class="m1">
                                <a href="single.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 footer-grid">
                    <div class="footer-grid-instagram">
                        <a href="single.html"><img src="images/9.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-grid-instagram">
                        <a href="single.html"><img src="images/10.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-grid-instagram">
                        <a href="single.html"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-grid-instagram">
                        <a href="single.html"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 footer-grid">

                    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Johannesburg, South Africa</p>
                    <p><a href="mailto:contact@example.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> property@absa.co.za</a></p>
                    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone" aria-hidden="true"></span>+27000000</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            <div class="footer-copy">
                <p>© 2016 ABSA Ltd. All rights reserved</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- //footer -->
<!-- for bootstrap working -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- //for bootstrap working -->
<!-- here stars scrolling icon -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
                var defaults = {
                containerID: 'toTop', // fading element id
                containerHoverID: 'toTopHover', // fading element hover id
                scrollSpeed: 1200,
                easingType: 'linear' 
                };
            */

            $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });

            });
    </script>
<!-- //here ends scrolling icon -->
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've Deleted Validation from the scripts but still nothing

Comment: See the answer below on debugging and lack of info. On that note, a quick glance at all the above shows you're nesting `forms` (register).

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to put some more info...It impossible to know what is really happening only by see some jquery and dependencies..

Second, (in chrome) right click on the element, click on "inspect", go to "Event Listeners" and click on "click".

You will see which are the event listeners of the buttons, and you will be able to investigate what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Add **method="post"** attribute to the first form tag and try again;

I mean;

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
```